# Different Header one One Sided Document Class Article

Tags: fancyhdr, single-sided

I am writing an article and as per the requirement of the journal article should be one side of paper. However, I am not able to adjust the different header on even and odd pages of the article. Minimum working example is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
  \usepackage{authblk}
  \usepackage{secdot}
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{newtxtext}
  \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{mathptmx}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \usepackage{calrsfs}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{\ifodd\value{page}\else\thepage{} Ahmed Arif\fi}
  \fancyhead[R]{\ifodd\value{page}Finance Paper \thepage\fi}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage[final]{graphicx}
  \usepackage[natbibapa,indexpackage]{apacite}
  \bibliographystyle{apacitex}
  %page margins
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm }
  \setlength\parindent{24pt}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{textgreek}
  \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
  \usepackage{libertineRoman}
  %line spacing
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \doublespacing
  \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
  \captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
  \usepackage{tabulary}
  \usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
  \usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable}
  \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
  \usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
  \usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
  \usepackage{caption}% <-- added
  \setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
  \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}
  \usepackage{pdflscape}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage{acro}
  \urlstyle{same}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \newcommand\independent{\protect\mathpalette{\protect\independenT}{\perp}}
  \def\independenT#1#2{\mathrel{\rlap{$#1#2$}\mkern2mu{#1#2}}}
  \usepackage{abstract}
  \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}
  \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
  \setlength{\footnotemargin}{.4em}
  \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}
  \renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
  \usepackage{lipsum}

  \title{My Finance Paper}
   \author{\sc{Ahmed Arif}}

   \begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a oneside document, left hand pages are not existing.

Comment: Then how we can put different header on even and odd page?

Comment: Change the option `oneside` to `twoside`?

Comment: In that case header is indented. How I can finish this indenting?

Comment: if you are submitting the article to a journal for publication, the journal editorial staff will reprocess it into the publication format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditionals in the header since the `page` counter would be definitive:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{\ifodd\value{page}\else\thepage{} Ahmed Arif\fi}
\fancyhead[R]{\ifodd\value{page}Finance Paper \thepage\fi}

\title{My Finance Paper}
\author{Ahmed Arif}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\sloppy\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

You can, of course, also use the `twoside` option, since this allows you to specify the use of `E`ven and `O`dd header placement (which only exists under that option):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage{} Ahmed Arif}
\fancyhead[RO]{Finance Paper \thepage}

%...
```

True, the page layout will be different, but that can be restored using [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), if needed.

Comment: Thank you Werner. The only problem that appears now is that it is headers are indented by one Tab space like a start of paragraph on the odd page.

Comment: @AhmedArif: I don't see that in my example. What do your `\fancyhead` statements look like?

Comment: Werner.. I have edited my question. Now I have provide the full preamble. May be some command is in conflict. Please have a look at the edited question. The header at odd page is not fully right indented

Comment: @AhmedArif: Aaahhh... you need to load [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (and it's accompanying settings) *after* [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and setting the `\geometry`.